# Move related products from Left Column to Main Content above tabs (Product Description, Product Reviews, etc)

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been reading through other posts and the one thing that eludes my problem is that the site I'm working does not use a `catalog.xml` file.

How would I go about moving `related products on the left column` over to the main content page for products?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `local.xml` for your theme, you can just use the following:

```
 <catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="product.info">
     <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
  </reference>
 </catalog_product_view>
```

Then edit `yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and add the following wherever you want them to appear:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
```

Comment: I've tried these options but nothing has shown results. I'll give it another go and maybe the changes take awhile.

Comment: You will need to refresh the `Layout Cache` in `System > Cache Management` for these changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code to local.xml. The code will first remove the current related product block then insert a new one below the product description container. It works for me.

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411538/2484533) for more information how to sort blocks.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="left">
        <!-- remove the block name from a parent -->
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <block>catalog.product.related</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- add the block name to a parent -->
        <action method="insert">
            <block>catalog.product.related</block>
            <siblingName></siblingName>
            <after>1</after>
        </action>
        <!--
            Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::insert() accepts multiple arguments,
            but by default it will insert the added block at the beginning
            of the list of child blocks.
        -->
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```